# Can we replace if statement with an object in C#

Tags: c#, oop, refactoring

Below is a method:

```
  private RiskFactor calculateMotoristRiskFactor()
    {               

        if (motorist.PointsOnLicense > 3
        || motorist.Age < 25)

            return RiskFactor.HighRisk;
        if (motorist.PointsOnLicense > 0)
            return RiskFactor.ModerateRisk;

        return RiskFactor.LowRisk;
    }
```

I don't want those if statements.

Can I use strategy pattern to solve this?
If yes then too I don't want each method in the different polymorphic class should have an **If statement** in it.

RiskFactor is an Enum

Any better way to make this more object oriented instead of procedural?

Comment: Enum names should be `CamelCased`.  Never use ALL_CAPS in .Net, except for preprocessor tokens.

Comment: Are you doing this because a strategy pattern is actually better, or just because you want to be more "object-oriented?"

Comment: I want to be more object oriented

Comment: Looks OO enough to me. I think the strategy pattern would only complicate the design here.

Comment: @alexantd Don't you think Single responsibility is violated here?

Comment: @Vicky: Not really; if you disagree, take a look at Tom W.'s answer, but it smells like pattern-itis to me.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you could have a `List<Tuple<Func<Motorist, bool>, RiskFactor>`:

```
var filters = new List<Tuple<Func<Motorist, bool>, RiskFactor>
{
    Tuple.Create(m => m.PointsOnLicense > 3, RiskFactor.HIGH_RISK),
    Tuple.Create(m => m.Age < 25, RiskFactor.HIGH_RISK),
    Tuple.Create(m => m.PointsOnLicense > 0, RiskFactor.MODERATE_RISK),
};
```

Then:

```
var risk = filters.Where(filter => filter.Item1(motorist))
                  .Select(filter => filter.Item2)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty(RiskFactor.LOW_RISK)
                  .First();
```

That at least makes it easy to add extra checks, and it just runs down them in order. It's a little bit fiddly - I might create a custom `Filter` type rather than the `Tuple` for example - but it should work...

Comment: ok, and the custom filter type should be inherited from Tuple?

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? I think this is a fine solution, especially replacing Tuples with a custom type as Jon suggests.

Comment: @Vicky No, the `Filter` type would be its own class that contains a `Func<Motorist,bool>` and exposes a `RiskFactor`. It could then be injected with the implementation of the predicate (such as `m => m.PointsOnLicense > 3`) and which `RiskFactor` to return when the predicate evaluates to true.

Comment: You could add the default entry to the list in the last position with `m => true` and then your extraction would simply be `var risk = filters.First(x => x.Item1(motorist)).Item2`

Comment: @Brian: True... although I'm not sure that's as clear as making it obvious that it's the default. Definitely an option to consider though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the strategy pattern should be the answer here - typically you would use a strategy if the particular *type* of motorist you are dealing with affects the behavior.

In your case you just have standard domain logic based on the properties of a motorist. I think the conditional handling is very appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Do away with the `RiskFactor` function entirely. Instead of the consuming code for that function, encapsulate the logic which requires its return value into seperate classes which perform the task differently.

For example, you could define an abstract class `Policy` which is inherited by `LowRiskPolicy`, `ModerateRiskPolicy` and `HighRiskPolicy`. These simply return values calculated according to the appropriate policy and the consuming code doesn't know or care what sort of policy they are. All the policy-specific logic is wrapped up in the policy.

Comment: No this is an Enum Value based on which the Premium is calculated

Comment: I can see that. I'm questioning why you need the Enum, and suggesting that you replace the code that uses it with polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need to be more object oriented only just to be more object oriented.
If it's only place in code where you are calculating risk and I assume there are number of other data calculated based on age and points of license I would leave your code as it is.

Except probably passing Motorist as parameter to the method of RiscCalculator class.

Just in case similar example here [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have a lot more code, but it will allow you to factor it out. You could create a policy class for each type of risk factor and collect them together. Something like this:

```
    public abstract class RiskPolicy
    {
        public abstract RiskFactor Risk { get; }
    }

    public class PointsPolicy : RiskPolicy
    {
        private readonly int _points;
        public PointsPolicy(int points)
        {
            _points = points;
        }

        public override RiskFactor Risk
        {
            get { return _points > 3 ? RiskFactor.HIGH_RISK : 
                         _points > 0 ? RiskFactor.MODERATE_RISK : RiskFactor.LOW_RISK; }
        }
    }

    public class AgePolicy : RiskPolicy
    {
        private readonly int _age;
        public AgePolicy(int age)
        {
            _age = age;
        }

        public override RiskFactor Risk
        {
            get { return _age < 25 ? RiskFactor.HIGH_RISK : RiskFactor.LOW_RISK; }
        }
    }
```